# PHP Memcached delete dead server from pool

Tags: php, memcached

there are two production servers and both servers contain memcached. E.g. web1 server is 192.168.1.1, the web2 is 192.168.1.2. Now both of servers are added to the memcached config on both servers.

```
$memcached = new Memcached('idname');

$memcached->setOption(Memcached::OPT_DISTRIBUTION, Memcached::DISTRIBUTION_CONSISTENT);
$memcached->setOption(Memcached::OPT_REMOVE_FAILED_SERVERS , true);
$memcached->setOption(Memcached::OPT_TCP_NODELAY, true);
$memcached->setOption(Memcached::OPT_SERVER_FAILURE_LIMIT, 1);
$memcached->setOption(Memcached::OPT_CONNECT_TIMEOUT, 5);
$memcached->setOption(Memcached::OPT_RETRY_TIMEOUT, 5);

$memcached->addServer(192.168.1.1, 11211);
$memcached->addServer(192.168.1.2, 11211);
```

If one of the server is dead the dead server is not removed from the pool despite on the OPT_REMOVE_FAILED_SERVERS option set as true, so in the case if e.g. the web2 is dead, the dead will run to lots of error.

Does anyone have any idea how it should be handled? I tried to use the getLastDisconnectedServer() and reinstance the Memcached() class, but I don't think this is the most efficient solution especially that the libmemcached contain a bug and the resetServerList() cannot be used properly.

Thank you in advance.